# Is there a more pythonic way to write multiple comparisons

Tags: python

I am writing a simple card game (Similar to Snap). I've got it working, without problems, but I feel that there ought to be a more elegant solution.
Given a set of win conditions:
Y beats R
R beats B
B beats Y
etc

I want to compare the two player's cards and assign both cards to the winner.
Caveat: I'm teaching at secondary school level (no OOP) and want to be able to discuss the resulting code with students.

I've left the final condition as an elif, as I wanted to go back and add extra cards to the list of options

The if - elif chain works without problems; I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution.

```
    #I have code that randomly selects from a list, but this is the basic 
    #idea:
    p1=input("enter r,y or b")  
    p2=input("enter r,y or b")  

    stack1=[]  
    stack2=[]  

    if   p1=="r" and p2=="b":  
        stack1.extend([p1,p2])  
    elif p1=="y" and p2=="r":  
        stack1.extend([p1,p2])  
    elif p1 =="b" and p2 =="y":  
        stack1.extend([p1,p2])  
    elif p2 =="r" and p1 =="b":  
        stack2.extend([p1,p2])  
    elif p2 =="y" and p1 =="r":  
        stack2.extend([p1,p2])             
    elif p2 =="b" and p1 =="y":  
        stack2.extend([p1,p2])  

    print(stack1)  
    print(stack2)
```

I've excerpted the code from the remainder - the cards are all randomly generated, so no user input is actually required.

Comment: The last three elifs can be shortend to `else: stack2.extend(....)`

Comment: how about `if p1 + p2 in {'rb', 'yr', 'by'}: stack.extend([p1, p2])` etc. ?

Comment: Thanks everyone for all your help.  I now have enough resources for a series of lessons. @OcasoProtal - I can't believe I missed that.   Chris_Rands - I've used this idea for the extension task.   RocketLL - that works nicely - and ties in with the rock-paper-scissors task that we did a while ago.    Goyo - I agree, and with some of them I'll be talking about that. This all came about because I found a student with over 1200 lines of code because he ws comparing every card with every other card in the deck

Comment: this is the neatest version of what I came up with: `stack1.extend([p1, p2]) if (p1 + p2) in ['rb', 'yr', 'by'] else stack2.extend([p1,p2])`

Answer (score 5):

Create a new dictionary with Y, R, B each mapping to 0, 1, 2.

```py
win_map = {"Y": 0, "R": 1, "B": 2}
```

We can see a cyclic relationship here. 0 beats 1, 1 beats 2, and 2 beats 0. The first two cases are easy to determine using a simple `>`, but taking the third case into account needs another method. With a bit of ingenuity, we can see that we can "wrap" by adding 1 and using a modulo operation `%`. `(0+1) % 3 == 1`, `(1+1) % 3 == 2`, and `(2+1) % 3 == 0`, and these 3 cases are the only cases where a winner is determined.

```py
if (win_map[p1] + 1) % 3 == win_map[p2]: ...  # p1 wins
else if (win_map[p2] + 1) % 3 == win_map[p1]: ... # p2 wins
```

I am not sure how well this will be conveyed to students though, but it is a cleaner solution.

Note: this method will not work with more cards, as the cyclic relationship will be broken.

Comment: +1 for elegance, this is definitely a big step to reduce duplication, but notice: for the "adding extra cards" requirement this will break (because every card only beats/loses to one card, so with e.g. 5 cards there will be pairs with no distinct winner)

Comment: @Adam.Er8 True, edited with a variable for card count.

Comment: It's got more to it, still - every card wins/loses only to a single option (because the % gives a single number). Every possible pair should have an outcome, like in Rock-Paper-Scissors-Lizard-Spock

Comment: @Adam.Er8 Ah, that's true. Edited.

Answer (score 3):

So your win conditions look like a collection of (winner, loser) pairs and comparing your `(p1, p2)` input to them looks like the simplest thing to do.

```
win_conditions = {
    ('y', 'r'),
    ('r', 'b'),
    ('b', 'y')
}

p1=input("enter r,y or b")
p2=input("enter r,y or b")

stack1=[]
stack2=[]

if (p1, p2) in win_conditions:
    stack1.extend([p1,p2])
elif (p2, p1) in win_conditions:
    stack2.extend([p1,p2])
else:
    raise ValueError('{} and {} cannot beat each other.'.format(p1, p2))
```

Note that the code can be simplified if you assume that the win conditions are exhaustive.

I think you will do your students a favor if you show them how to improve readability by encansulating low-level operations in functions with proper names so that the intent is more obvious.

```
def beats(p1, p2):
    return (p1, p2) in win_conditions

if beats(p1, p2):
    stack1.extend([p1,p2])
elif beats(p2, p1):
    stack2.extend([p1,p2])
else:
    raise ValueError('"{}" and "{}" cannot beat each other.'.format(p1, p2))
```

Maybe you can find a better name for whatever you want to achieve by extending the list.

Answer (score 1):

"Standard" solution for small scale problem like yours is to put all possibilities into map:

```
result_map = { ('r', 'b'): 1, ('b', 'y'): 1, ('y', 'r'): 1, 
('b', 'r'): 2, ('y', 'b'): 2, ('r', 'y'): 2 }
v = result_map.get((p1, p2), None)
if v == 1:
    stack1.extend([p1, p2])
elif v == 2:
    stack2.extend([p1, p2])
```

Why like this? Because it gives you easy way to change win / loose condition (just change a dictionary), win / loose rules can be completely arbitrary and it is easy to follow code (image you've some weird if-else condition and someone else comes looking at this code and wonders, what is going on and why).

Answer (score 0):

You're repeating the same thing too many times, there are two `extend` calls that are repeated 3 times each.

You could greatly simplify your code by using the `or` keyword:

```
# extend to "stack1"
if (p1 == "r" and p2 == "b") or (p1 == "y" and p2 == "r") or (p1 == "b" and p2 == "y"):
  stack1.extend([p1, p2])

# extend to "stack2"
elif (p2 == "r" and p1 == "b") or (p2 == "y" and p1 == "r") or (p2 == "b" and p1 == "y"):
  stack2.extend([p1, p2])
```

Good luck.

Comment: I would argue that you are also repeating the same thing too many times: the same long chain of comparisons with only two variables swapped. Encapsulating that in a function not only improves readability and clarifies intent but also eliminates duplication and abstracts out a low level detail (how do we find out wo the winner is?) from the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to compare, maybe it can be used in for loop or dict map to help refactor your code, if necessary and performance not important.

```
from operator import and_ 
from functools import partial

def compare(a, b, c, d):
    return and_(a == c, b == d) 

p1 = 'r'
p2 = 'b'
cmp_p1_p2 = partial(compare, p1, p2)
cmp_p2_p1 = partial(compare, p2, p1)

cmp_p1_p2('r', 'b')
# True
cmp_p2_p1('b', 'r')
# True
```